# Custom Python module structure

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am currently doing a personal coding project and I am trying to build a module, but I don't know why my structure doesn't work the way it's supposed to:

```
\mainModule
    __init__.py
    main.py
    \subModule_1
        __init__.py
        someCode_1.py
        someCode_2.py
    \subModule_2
        __init__.py
        otherCode.py
```

I want to be able to run the following code from `main.py`:

```
>>> from subModule_1 import someCode_1
>>> someCode_1.function()
"Hey, this works!"
>>> var = someCode_2.someClass("blahblahblah")
>>> var.classMethod1()
>>> "blah blah blah"
>>> from subModule2 import otherCode
>>> otherCode("runCode","#ff281ba0")
```

However, when I try to import `someCode_1`, for example, it returns an `AttributeError`, and I'm not really sure why. Is it to do with the `__init__.py` file?

## REVISIONS

- Minimal, Complete and verifiable (I hope...)

  ```
  \mainDir
      __init__.py # blank file
      main.py
      \subDir
          __init__.py # blank file
          codeFile.py
  ```

  Using this...

  ```
  #main.py file
  import subDir
  subDir.codeFile.function()
  ```

  And this...

  ```
  #codeFile.py file
  def function():
      return "something"
  ```

  ...it returns the same problem mentioned above**.

** The exact error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\...\mainDir\main.py", line 2, in <module>
    subDir.codeFile.function()
AttributeError: module 'subDir' has no attribute 'codeFile'
```

Credits to @jonrsharpe: Thanks for showing me how to use Stack Overflow correctly.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Also you seem to be saying you want to run an interactive session *"from `main.py`"*, which doesn't entirely make sense.

Comment: Might be caused by some module level code in `someCode_1` which is executed upon import. WHat is the exact error message?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Sorry, I meant compiling and running `main.py` using the interpreter (sorry, rookie mistake)

Comment: @schwobaseggl 

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\...\main.py", line 10, in <module>
    subDir.codeFile.function()
AttributeError: module 'subDir' has no attribute 'codeFile'`

Comment: Make sure your current working directory is neither `mainDir` nor `subDir` when you perform the test.

Comment: @jez I don't understand. Are you saying that I should run the interpreter from a different source?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options to make this work.

Either this:

```
from subdir import codeFile
codeFile.function()
```

Or:

```
import subdir.codeFile
subdir.codeFile.function()
```

Answer (score 1):

When you `import subDir`, it does three things:

1. executes the code in `mainDir/subDir/__init__.py` (i.e. in this case does nothing, because this file is empty)
2. imports the resulting module under the name `subDir` locally, which will in turn make it an attribute of the `mainDir` module;
3. registers the new import globally in the `sys.modules` dictionary (because the `import` is being performed from a parent module `mainDir`, the name is completed to `'mainDir.subDir'` for the purposes of this registration);

What it does **not** do, because it hasn't been told to, is import `subDir.codeFile`.  Therefore, the code in `codeFile.py` has not been run and the name `codeFile` has not yet been imported into the namespace of `mainDir.subDir`. Hence the `AttributeError` when trying to access it.  If you were to add the following line to `mainDir/subDir/__init__.py` then it would work:

```
import codeFile
```

Specifically, this will:

1. run the code in `codeFile.py`
2. add the resulting module as an attribute of the `mainDir.subDir` module
3. store a reference to it as yet another entry in `sys.modules`, this time under the name `mainDir.subDir.codeFile`.

You could also achieve the same effect from higher up the module hierarchy, by saying `import subDir, subDir.codeFile` instead of just `import subDir` in your `mainDir.main` source file.

NB: When you test this from the command line or IDE, make sure that your current working directory (queried by `os.getcwd()`, changed using `os.chdir(wherever)` ) is neither `mainDir` nor `subDir`.  Work from somewhere else—e.g. the parent directory of `mainDir`.  Working from inside a module will lead to unexpected results.

Comment: This makes so much sense - I'm amending this now to get it to work (I had no idea how the import keyword actually worked, but this clears up a lot of smoke for me)

Comment: Question - if I didn't want to have my current working directory to be `main.py` (which you accurately guessed it would be), "where" would I run the interpreter from? Does it even _matter_?

Comment: Unfortunately, I received an error from putting `import codeFile` into `mainDir\subDir\__init__.py`: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'codeFile'`

Comment: Two things matter:  (1) that you're not working inside a module;  (2) that every module you want to find (in this case the directory `mainDir`) is either in your current working directory—right at your feet, so to speak—or inside one of the directories listed on your system path (`sys.path`).  Otherwise `mainDir` will not be found when you try to import it.  (But the `mainDir` directory *itself* should *not* be part of `sys.path`.)

Comment: Re your `ModuleNotFoundError`:  another thing you have to work around is the fact that modules are cached.  If you change module code, you have to `reload` it,  (first reload the sub-sub-modules, then the sub-modules, then the module).  That can get really tedious, so sometimes the easiest way is to re-start Python each time you try changing the architecture like this.   Another problem is the difference between python 2.x and 3.x—my solution works in 2.x but am currently trying to figure out why it fails with `ImportError: no module named 'subDir'` in 3.x

Comment: I agree - I reloaded my code by exiting and re-opening the module, but that didn't seem to have an effect. In the meantime, I'm going to use @DonTintoretto's solution until I understand the situation better. It's not my ideal solution but it'll have to do for now. (BTW I'm using python 3.6.0, if that helps)